# CPP undefined reference to function in same file

Tags: android, c++, sqlite

While compiling a CPP project into an .so library it generates the following errors :

```
 ...  
jni/core/src/sqlite3/sqlite3c++.h:26: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3cpp::database::mp_checkSqliteError(int, std::string)'  
jni/core/src/sqlite3/sqlite3c++.h:51: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3cpp::query::compile()'  
jni/core/src/sqlite3/sqlite3c++.h:51: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3cpp::database::mp_checkSqliteError(int, std::string)'  
jni/core/src/sqlite3/sqlite3c++.h:53: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3cpp::query::compile()'  
...
```

Where those files are :
part of **sqlite3c++.h** :

```
.....
#include "sqlite3.h"

#ifndef MFDEPSAPI
#define MFDEPSAPI
#endif

namespace sqlite3cpp
{
    class MFDEPSAPI database
    {
    public:
        database(std::string databaseFile): mp_transactionInProgress(false), mp_SQLITE_db(0) { if(databaseFile.empty()) return; mp_checkSqliteError(sqlite3_open_v2(databaseFile.c_str(), &mp_SQLITE_db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX, 0), "opening database"); }
        ~database();

        ....

    class MFDEPSAPI query
    {
    public:
        query(database& db, const char* strQuery);
        ~query();

        void compile();

        ....
    }
}
```

part of **sqlite3c++.cpp** :

```
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include "sqlite3c++.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace sqlite3cpp
{
    ....

    int database::mp_checkSqliteError(int retVal, const std::string description)
    {
        switch(retVal)
        {
        case -1:
            cerr << "non-typed sqlite library error: " << description << "\n";
            return retVal;
            break;
        case SQLITE_ERROR:
        case SQLITE_MISUSE:
        case SQLITE_FULL:
        case SQLITE_NOMEM:
        case SQLITE_INTERRUPT:
        case SQLITE_INTERNAL:
        case SQLITE_PERM:
        case SQLITE_CORRUPT:
        case SQLITE_CANTOPEN:
        case SQLITE_AUTH:
        case SQLITE_RANGE:
        case SQLITE_NOTADB:
            cerr << "sqlite error: (" << retVal << ") " << sqlite3_errmsg(mp_SQLITE_db) << ", description: \"" << description << "\"" << "\n";
            return retVal;
            break;
        default:
            return retVal;
        };
    }

    .....    

    query::query( database& db, const char* strQuery ) : mp_db(db), mp_isValid(false), mp_strQuery(strQuery), mp_currentIndex(0), mp_SQLITE_statement(0)
    {
    }
}
```

It's building with cygwin via nkd-build.cmd for android with this **Android.mk**:

```
LOCAL_PATH:=$(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

 ####  sqlite3
# Here we give our module name and source file(s)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := core/src/sqlite3
LOCAL_MODULE := sqlite3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := core/src/sqlite3/sqlite3.c
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
#include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

 #### Project
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libgame
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra
LOCAL_LDLIBS :=  -llog -lGLESv2
LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += exceptions
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libsqlite3
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := liblog libGLESv2

# To build the whole .so
FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/core/src/*.cpp)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
INCLUDE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/core/src/*.h)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(INCLUDE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

It's probably just something I missed or got wrong configured.
Feel free to ask if more files or something is needed.

Comment: mp_checkSqliteError is using a `const` `std::string`, have you tried without that `const` ?

Comment: Are those member functions declared in the header file ? with the same signature ?

Comment: @AntoineGuillen Top level const is irrelevant; it is ignored as part of the function signature.  (Of course, one would expect the arguments to be `std;;string const&`.  And `std::strring&` and `std::string const&` _do_ make a difference.)

Comment: If you're using `make` to build (as the `.mk` suffix suggests), the actual commands should appear on the screen during the build.  So do you ever compile  `sqlite3c++.cpp`?  And do you link in `sqlite3c++.o`?

Comment: @JamesKanze I indeed haven't fount sqlite3c++.cpp while seeking through the whole commands. So it seems not to be compiled. I don't know what you mean with the "link in sqlite3c++.o"

Comment: @JamesKanze adding the sqlite3c++.cpp to the LOCAL_SRC_FILES did the trick